# Can I redirect a POST request to an external GET request in routes.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails 3 application where I want to redirect an incoming POST request to an external GET request. The external URL should include some of the POST data.

This is of courses trivial to do in a controller, but can it be done in routes.rb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you ask if it's possible to use in routes.rb syntax like 
`match "/form_with_post_request" => "http://external_url.com?param1=x&param2=y"` ?

It is not possible in routes.rb. You should indeed use controller for that.

Comment: As I expected. Solved it using a rack app, should be a little more light weight than using a controller.